# shouldInteractWith url textview delegate not called in ios9 but working in ios10?

Tags: ios, swift3

shouldInteractWith url textview delegate not called in ios9 but i have implemented ios9 delegate method also. Code is below. If someone knows whats the issue fix then please let me know. thanks in advance for any help

```
import UIKit

class UrNestTermsView: UIView {

// Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var termsTextView: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var termsUrNestCheckBox: UrNestCheckBox!
@IBOutlet weak var subscribeUrNestCheckBox: UrNestCheckBox!
@IBOutlet weak var subscribeTextView: UITextView!

fileprivate let fontOfTerms = UIFont.systemFont(with: 10)
fileprivate let labelTextColor = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 102/255, green: 110/255, blue: 111/255, alpha: 1)

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.setUp()
 }
}

extension UrNestTermsView: UITextViewDelegate {

func setUp() {
    self.subscribeTextView.textColor = labelTextColor
    self.subscribeTextView.font = fontOfTerms
    self.setUpTextView()
}

func setUpTextView() {

    // You must set the formatting of the link manually
    let linkAttributeTermsOfService = [
        NSLinkAttributeName: NSURL(string: "https://www.apple.com")!,
        NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: labelTextColor
        ] as [String : Any]
    let linkAttributePolicy = [
        NSLinkAttributeName: NSURL(string: "https://www.google.com")!,
        NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: labelTextColor
        ] as [String : Any]
    let linkAttributePaymentsTermsOfService = [
        NSLinkAttributeName: NSURL(string: "https://www.amazon.com")!,
        NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: labelTextColor
        ] as [String : Any]
    let linkAttributeGuestRefundPolicy = [
        NSLinkAttributeName: NSURL(string: "https://www.yahoo.com")!,
        NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: labelTextColor
        ] as [String : Any]
    let linkAttributeHostGuaranteeTerms = [
        NSLinkAttributeName: NSURL(string: "https://www.assembla.com")!,
        NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue,
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: labelTextColor
        ] as [String : Any]


    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: kTermsAndPolicy)

    // Set the 'click here' substring to be the link
    attributedString.setAttributes(linkAttributeTermsOfService, range: NSMakeRange(33, 16))
    attributedString.setAttributes(linkAttributePolicy, range: NSMakeRange(51, 6))
    attributedString.setAttributes(linkAttributePaymentsTermsOfService, range: NSMakeRange(59, 25))
    attributedString.setAttributes(linkAttributeGuestRefundPolicy, range: NSMakeRange(102, 19))
    attributedString.setAttributes(linkAttributeHostGuaranteeTerms, range: NSMakeRange(127, 20))


    attributedString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: fontOfTerms, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length-1))
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: labelTextColor, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length-1))

    self.termsTextView.delegate = self
    self.termsTextView.attributedText = attributedString

    let attributedStringOfSubscribe = NSMutableAttributedString(string: kSubscribe)
    attributedStringOfSubscribe.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: fontOfTerms, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedStringOfSubscribe.length))
    attributedStringOfSubscribe.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: labelTextColor, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedStringOfSubscribe.length))

    self.subscribeTextView.delegate = self
    self.subscribeTextView.attributedText = attributedStringOfSubscribe
}

//For iOS 7...9
@available(iOS, deprecated: 10.0)
 func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
    return true
}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
 func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
    return true
 }

}
```

Comment: Hi, did you figure out the solution?

Comment: Hi, still i doesn't found a solution

Answer (score 11):

you must check `Selectable` in storyboard or do it in code :

```
textView.isSelectable = true
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
@available(iOS, deprecated: 10.0)
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith url: URL, in characterRange: NSRange) -> Bool {
    return true
}

//For iOS 10
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith url: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have tried but not working for ios9